# java recommended way for shutting down multiple user sessions

Tags: java, multithreading, session

We want to disconnect our clients from the server.

So we sent out some messages to the sessions, which include basically some commands like "close yourself"l

So in general I do something like this:

```
for (Session session : sessions) {
        closeSession(session);
        while(!verifyClosed(session)){
            closeSession(session);
            retries++;
            if(retries==10){
                retries = 0;
                break;
            }
        };
    }
```

Now I would like to give some seconds (let's say 5) for each session to get closed before doing some sigterm kill methods.

So what would be the preferred way:

1. Doing the loop with a maximum of 5 seconds delay for each session close procedure.

   OR
2. Start for each session a thread that does this procedure so the sessions should be closed at the same time.

   ```
   for (Session session : sessions) {
       startClosingThread(session);
   }
   ```

**Update:**

I notice that some users falsly hung up to much on the word "Session", the problem is not the SessionHandling at all. If i send a closing message or disconnect the Socket does not matter. This is not the problem.

You could replace the word Session with UserThread.

The problem for what i need some advice is: 
Closing a "UserThread" will take some time, so now wait for each thread to be closed and step to the next one, or start for each UserThread its own repsonsible Closing Thread to work on all Threads at the same time.

Comment: You can simply add all sessions in come collection or queue, then periodically traverse it, sending close commands to each session. If some session was not succeeded to close--add it back in the collection. Do it until the collection becomes empty or retry limit exceeds.

Comment: '`sigterm` kill methods' to kill what? What is a 'user session' in this scenario? What's wrong with just closing the socket?

Comment: Is sending the closing command a blocking or non-blocking operation? What kind of connection do you have to the sessions that you can do some sigterm kill method?

Comment: @EJP sigterm to kill a process. Socketclosing is an unreliable way (for that we have the "close yourself" methods). The session could hang in an endless loop or reside in a forzen state so it's not guaranteed that the process will end if the socket is disconnected.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: But the problem would still exist. Start a responsible closing thread for a session while traversing the next session or traverse all sessions in the same thread. It doesn't matter if i remove them from the queue or not.

Comment: 1. Kill *what* process? 2. Socket closing is not 'unreliable': the symptoms you mention can only occur in poorly programmed client code. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Send the session close request on all sessions, wait your five seconds, then check all sessions.  That way the session closes can happen in parallel without starting a whole bunch of new threads.

Comment: Yes atm it's like this